# Use latexindent.pl with `BeautifyLatex` in sublime text

Tags: mac, sublime-text, latexindent

I was trying to use [`latexindent.pl`](https://github.com/cmhughes/latexindent.pl) with the package [`BeautifyLatex`](https://github.com/ketan/BeautifyLatex) in SublimeText 3 on OS X El Capitan . When I tried to save tex file, there was an error:

```
Error: can't specify None for path argument
```

I googled about this error. The path of `latexindent.pl` became the suspect. Typing `which latexindent` on the terminal, I saw `latexindent` installed.

```
$ which latexindent
/Library/TeX/texbin/latexindent
```

Typing `echo $PATH` on the terminal, I saw the current path includes `/Library/TeX/texbin`, which contains `latexindent`. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

There's a well-known issue with command-line tools in GUI applications on OS X, starting with El Capitan. Basically, when launched from the Dock, Spotlight, etc. they inherit a very restricted `PATH` (this was true on earlier versions of OS X, but you could usually adjust it somehow). However, this can be easily fixed by installing the [Fix Mac Path](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Fix%20Mac%20Path) plugin, which ensures the `PATH` in ST is the same as the `PATH` in the terminal.

Comment: I did install `Fix Mac Path`. Unfortunately, the same error `can't specify None for path argument` still exists when I tried to save files.

Comment: Hmmm... Do you get any more information with that error?

Comment: Have you added `"additional_path_items": ["/Library/TeX/texbin"]` to your User settings?

Comment: @ig0774 From the end of Sublime text 3, no other error message was shown.

Comment: @r-stein I did not add that path. After adding this item, the error still exists. In the terminal, I can use `latexindent file.tex`.

Comment: @semibruin You could try to open the ST console ``ctrl+` `` and type `import os; os.environ["PATH"]` this should contain the path to latexindent. Otherwise write `os.environ["path"] += ":/Library/TeX/texbin"` and try to execute that command again.

Comment: @semibruin: the problem may be `latexindent` vs `latexindent.pl`, which you could test by running `sudo ln -s /Library/TeX/texbin/latexindent.pl /Library/TeX/texbin/latexindent` from the terminal. If that fixes things, this is a bug and should be reported to the BeautifyLatex project.

Comment: @ig0774 Great! It works now. A minor thing is that I assumed you meant `sudo ln -s /Library/TeX/texbin/latexindent /Library/TeX/texbin/latexindent.pl`. To fix this problem, I need three items. (I did experiment, and found that all three are necessary.) The first is to install `Fix mac path` (@ig0774). The second is to add the path `"additional_path_items": ["/Library/TeX/texbin"] ` to the User settings of `BautifyLatex`. (@r-stein). The last is to execute the link between `latexindent` and `latexindent.pl`. Thanks all very much. I will report this to the BeautifyLatex project.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick heads-up here... in Sierra this path business is, again, messy. Indeed using `Fix Mac Path`, adding the proper path to the user preferences, and finally doing the symbolic link, still results in the dreaded `None`

I'm drilling down through the whole mess now and will report back if I ever manage to decode what they've done this time :)

Comment: Sorry to comment on my own post... but... it appears that `Popen` doesn't work / blocks / hangs under Sierra, making the `Fix Mac Path` approach at path-fixing, fail. I'll post a bug report there once the 'official release' of Sierra hits the streets.

Comment: Did you figure something out here? I have the same problem. Tried what is stated above, but still get the same error.

Comment: @eivindml I did a fix here-  https://github.com/flipphillips/BeautifyLatex